# Combining readline() and for loop without using next() in python

Tags: python, readline

I am trying to read multiple text files in a folder to plot a specific column(last column) of each of the file. I have used the following code to do that:

```
file_library = os.listdir(path)
for book in file_library:
 file = os.path.join(path, book)
  if file.endswith(".txt"):
    f = open(file, "r")
        for line in f:
            reads = read_ydata(f)
                print reads
        f.close()
```

where read_ydata function is defined as follows:

```
y_values = []
line = filename.readline()
while line != '':
 y_val = line[line.rfind(' ') + 1:]
 y_values.append(float(y_val))
 line = filename.readline()
return y_values
```

Now when i run this i get an error:
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
and if i replace it with next() i get the error: StopIteration.

Plz advice as to how to get rid of these errors or to implement my logic..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *either* `next()` and looping, *or* use `.readline()`, but don't mix both.

Using the file object as an iterable creates an internal buffer that would create confusion for what position the next `.readline()` will read from (which does not use a buffer).

Just use `next(filename)` instead of `filename.readline()` and you are good.

Both `next()` and `.readline()` return the line *with* the newline included, make sure you strip the line of whitespace before you test for the empty string.

Note that you can use `.rsplit()` to split off a value from the end of a line:

```
y_val = line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
```

or use `.rpartition()`:

```
y_val = line.rpartition(' ')[-1]
```

Your function does not need to use a `while` loop; you could also just use a `for` loop and break when the line is empty:

```
y_values = []
for line in filename:
    if not line.strip():
        return y_values
    y_val = line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
    y_values.append(float(y_val))
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot... i was looking for such kind of alternative to readline() which u provided!..it worked :-)